# Bloom effect using downscaling (downsampling) technique using OpenGL/GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Hello I'm trying to implement Bloom effect in my program. In fact, I've already implemented the effect using a highlight pass and a separate gaussian blur pass.

Here's an example:

Bright pass texture:

[image]

Gaussian blur render pass (2 internal passes for this effect):

[image]

And finally the final pass (brightPass + BlurPass):

[image]

(I want to precise I don't have implemented HDR tone mapping yet).

But I found a very interesting article from intel:

```
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/compute-shader-hdr-and-bloom
```

It said :

"First the bright pass is performed where values below a specified threshold are filtered out. The bright pass output is then downscaled by half 4 times. Each of the downscaled bright pass outputs are blurred with a separable Gaussian filter and then added to the next higher resolution bright pass output."

I understood how it works but I did not understand how to perform texture downscaling using OpenGL. However I know if I use glGenerateMipmap() function (at the initialization of my FBO) with 4 mipmap levels I think I will have my 4 downscaled texture directly with the desired format (1/16, 1/8, 1/4 and 1/2) like it's written in the article.

But my problem is I can't find the way to do this!

Does it exist a way to bind the other textures generated using mipmaping and use them in the fragment shader? Should I have to render the bright pass 4 times with 4 separates FBOs applying different formats (1/16, ...). I think it's a solution but it's probably not correct about the performance. I think the bright pass should be rendered once using the window max size and then using the downscaled textures (mipmap) already loaded in memory but I don't know how to bind and use them into my shaders! I'm really lost.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: One problem you will run into with downsizing the image is artifacts when combining the images into the final form. You have to get the sweet spot between Texture Size , Gaussian Blur Offset and Speed. The smaller the texture the smaller your Gaussian Blur Offset needs to be to avoid artifacts on the screen. The larger your texture the larger the larger the Gaussian Blur Offset can be but the slower the shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use **textureLod**, as BDL suggested, but I think that there is no real need for this.
Once the required mipmap levels are generated, the right level will be selected automatically depending on the size of the active render buffer.
The main idea of the article you have mentioned, is that they perform several blurring steps on differently sized sources. 
After mipmap levels were generated, you will have 4 mipmap levels that represent 1/16, 1/8, 1/4 and 1/2 scaled textures from bright pass. 
Each of this buffers you should blur, using the render buffer of the same size (1/16, 1/8, 1/4 and 1/2 correspondingly).
If the render buffer, you are rendering to is 1/16 scale of the source texture from the bright pass, than the 4-th mipmap level will be used. So you do not need to specify mipmap level manually.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Let's take an example: the bright pass texture format is 1024x720. Let's try to recover the mipmap level 3 (128x90). Like you said I just have to create a FBO and RBO + texture attached to it (so the color texture and the RBO are initialized with the dimension 128x90). So when I execute my bluring pass I apply the gaussian blur algorithm on a 128x90 bright texture (mipmap level 3). But the problem is I need to blur a 1024x720 texture(the max precision). So I think the right solution is like you say to use the function textureLod in the fragment shader. Are you agree?

Comment: I think I need to re-scale the low level texture to higher level but keeping the low resolution (128x90 -> 1024x720) before applying blur effect. I thought an intermediate render pass with in input the bright render pass texture and recover my 4 downscaled bright textures. Next all I need to do is to bind them separatly within the bluring pass. Like my FBO (the one into the bluring pass) is scaled in 1024x720 the blur algorithm will be applied this time on a 1024x720 low level texture. What do you think about this ?

Comment: But I think the function textureLod should avoid the intermediate render passes and directly into the bluring pass selecting the right level of mipmap in my fragment shader.

Comment: @user1364743, you said: 

`Let's take an example: the bright pass texture format is 1024x720. Let's try to recover the mipmap level 3 (128x90). Like you said I just have to create a FBO and RBO + texture attached to it (so the color texture and the RBO are initialized with the dimension 128x90). So when I execute my bluring pass I apply the gaussian blur algorithm on a 128x90 bright texture (mipmap level 3).`

You are absolutelly right. You do not need to perform blur at the max resolution.

Comment: There is just no sense in it. Blurring of downscaled image is not so costly as blurring original image, while the result is almost the same.

Comment: More over, in the article, they mentioned that several images were used, that have different downscale rate. This allows using the same blurring kernel and get different blurring radiuses.

Comment: You downscale image and you lost some amount of details, and it is just what needed.
Then, if you process the blurring step in upscaled resolution, or perform blurring step at the resolution of downscaled image, the result would be the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78098/discussion-between-user1364743-and-podgorskiy).

Answer (score 1):

You can access a specific mipmap-level in a shader using the

```
gvec4 textureLod(gsampler2D sampler, vec2 P, float lod);
```

method, where lod specifies the mipmap level. ([link to documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/textureLod.xhtml)).